# My mac is rebooting everytime I login

Tags: macos, bug, shutdown, restart

I have downloaded [these apps](https://github.com/siong1987/shortcuts/releases) to conveniently shutdown or restart my MAC from spotlight. Usually I used the shutdown app which worked great. Today I used the restart app. Since then my MAC is restarting gives me the login screen, I type the password, the desktop starts to show, and before it finishes loading, boom, another restart.

I noticed that when logging in, the preview app is opened again (it was open when I ran the restart command), so one idea I have, is that somehow the OS is relaunching the restart app, causing a new restart. Yet I'm not sure, could be totally bug from Apple, or anything else.

- I did use the restart app in the past a few times without a problem.
- The same problem was about two weeks ago, but only one restart happened, then the computer worked fine. I'm not sure, but I think that then I did **not** use the restart app. But I'm very vague with my memory on this one, because it was only one restart, so I didn't think there is a problem.

I tried, while being on the login screen, to not type the password but press the restart and shutdown buttons at the bottom. Also tried leaving the computer not connected to the electricity for about 3 hours. Nothing changed.

What can I do to get it working again?

In case it makes any difference:

- Mac Mini (mid 2011)
- Yosemite (updated about a 5-7 weeks ago)

Comment: The code is designed to restart on Error!

Comment: Ouch - Nasty one! Have to figure a way to get the app off the drive, from another machine or starting it in Target Disk mode.

Answer (score 1):

After reading a bit through the internet I found the 'safe mode', there I deleted some random files from the desktop, and changed the dock settings so it is always visible (I don't think these had any effect). Then I restarted and made sure the little checkbox next to '' is empty (probably this made the effect). When the computer started I could log in, but it is still weird, the desktop background image disappears and comes back, no dock, ... see my [followup question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170374/my-mac-is-loading-andthe-background-is-flashing-the-dock-also-does-not-show).

The next time I logged in I moved all the apps to the trash, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

It is not your Apple OS X responsible but the app you downloaded.

Quick look in to the code shows that it will restart if error is reported without proper classification of the error.

OS X has those as well, but most are ignored and it will continue to load.

Here is some material on that topic:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1134/_index.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4505664

and apparently working one here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6105338

As @Tetsujin pointed out, shut down and boot from external drive then remove that app.

Or even better use what @ Mr Rabbit is recommending.

Comment: Or try safe booting (hold the left Shift key while powering on, until the Apple logo w/ progress bar appears), this should disable the automatic opening of applications at login, allowing you to disable/remove the app.

Comment: Alternately you could boot into Single User mode (command+S while powering on) and remove it via command line.